# Using geom_text to print multiple text lines, each in a unique location

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am trying to print the equation for each regression line on my plot. The equations are overlapping each other so that only one of the equations is visible. I would like to print each equation in a unique spot so that they don't overlap. Ideally I would like them all right below, above and beside eachother.

This is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
all_rates = read.csv("file.txt")
j=30

lm_eqn <- function(df){
        m <- lm(unlist(df[3]) ~ unlist(df[2]), df);
        eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2,
                list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2),
                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
        as.character(as.expression(eq));
}

for(i in unique(gsub('_[0-9]+', '', all_rates[,1]))){
        rates <- all_rates[grep(i, all_rates[,1]),]
        freq = unlist(rates[2])
        temp = unlist(rates[3])
        exn = unlist(rates[4])
        p = ggplot(rates, aes(freq,temp)) + geom_point(data=rates, aes(freq,temp,group=exn,colour=exn)) + geom_smooth(data=rates, aes(freq,temp,group=exn,colour=exn),method = "lm",fill=NA) + geom_text(aes(x = 5, y = j), label = lm_eqn(rates), parse = TRUE, color = factor(exn), size=5) 
        ggsave(paste0(i, ".pdf"))
}
```

file.txt

```
clothing,freq,temp,exon
coat_1,0.3,10,1
coat_1,0.9,0,1
coat_1,0.1,20,1
coat_2,0.5,20,2
coat_2,0.3,15,2
coat_2,0.1,5,2
scarf,0.4,30,1
scarf,0.2,20,1
scarf,0.1,10,1
```

**UPDATE**

This is my updated code. I cannot get the colours to match up with the colours of the line and I cannot get ride of some of the messy characters in the text like ~ and "

```
library(ggplot2)
all_rates = read.csv("file.txt")

lm_eqn <- function(df){
        m <- lm(unlist(df[3]) ~ unlist(df[2]), df);
        eq <- substitute(y == a + b * x*","~~r^2~"="~r2,
                list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2),
                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
        as.character(as.expression(eq));
}

for(i in unique(gsub('_[0-9]+', '', all_rates[,1]))){
        rates <- all_rates[grep(i, all_rates[,1]),]
        num = 20 + length(unique(rates[,1])) - 1
        freq = unlist(rates[2])
        temp = unlist(rates[3])
        exn = unlist(rates[4])
        p = ggplot(rates, aes(freq,temp)) + geom_point(data=rates, aes(freq,temp,group=factor(exn),colour=factor(exn))) + geom_smooth(data=rates, aes(freq,temp,group=factor(exn),colour=factor(exn)),method = "lm",fill=NA)
        yval = 30
        for (k in unique(rates[,1])){
                sub_rates <- rates[rates[1] == toString(k),]
                p = p + annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = yval, label = lm_eqn(sub_rates), colour="red")
                yval = yval + 5
        }
        ggsave(paste0(i, ".pdf"))
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the `annotate()` layer in ggplot.  See http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html

Comment: @Tiffany I edited my code a little bit. I cannot get the line colours to match the line though, and I cannot make the text look "neat" using the annotate method, theres many nonsense characters that exist in there

Comment: What exactly are you trying to plot? Are you trying to plot x=freq, y=temp, with data grouped by clothing or exon? If you group by exon, scarf is mixed with coat 1. More specifically, which combination of variables yields the lines you are regressing on?

Comment: @Tiffany I create a separate plot for scarf and also for coat. Within the coat plot I have two regression lines, one for coat 1 and one for coat 2. Up until this point everything is working for me. What isn't working is that I would like to display the line equation(y= b + mx) and r^2 value for each regression line. The problem is that the regression lines are being printed on top of each other so that only the last regression line is printed.